# How to add Autosize script to Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, autosize

I am still learning Wordpress so forgive me if this is a stupid question but I am trying to add the [Autosize](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/) script to a page on my website and I am kind of lost. How do you add scripts to Wordpress? And how do I call it on a specific page with the `textarea` element that I want to autosize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include the scripts to WordPress you need to use `wp_enqueue_script` [Documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) Since you will need to call the JS to target the `textarea`, use the function in a custom.js file and include that too.

```
function autoresize_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'auto-resize', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/autoresize.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'autoresize_scripts' );
```

The above code will be used in `functions.php`

If you need to call it on a specific page:

Use `is_page` function in WordPress:

```
if( is_page( 2 ) ) // 2 is the page id
{
    // Target textarea with JS
}
```

And if you want to target many pages with the `textarea` element, WordPress will automatically take care as it is added to `footer.php` which is loaded in all the web pages.

Comment: What is the purpose of the custom.js? What do I put in this file?

Comment: If the JS plugin required targeting of element, then you need to add it in custom.js